# Python: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cos

Tags: python-3.x, trigonometry

Python: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sin

I have :

np.cos(2*(omega_b*t+phase_b))

where
phase_b=np.random.uniform(0,np.pi)
and omega_b = -5.014986158718046e-08

Comment: What is the value of t?